# JS delays two animations in one click event

Tags: javascript, function, navigation, nav

I am creating an off canvas navigation with CSS and JS. Everything works fine except that there's a delay in the following click event:

```
$('.open-nav').click(function(){
    $('#trigg, #container').animate({left: "200"}, 300);
});
```

By clicking the .open-nav button, both the #trigg and #container div should move 200 pixels to the right within 300 milliseconds, starting at the same time. But the #trigg div starts the animation before the #container does.
What can I do?

I already tried "queue: false" but it's still delayed.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: two animate() functions on one click. delay() problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398372/jquery-two-animate-functions-on-one-click-delay-problem)

Comment: Could you please tell me where to specifically put the "queue" in my function? I'm new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Tried using CSS3 animations instead?

```
$('.open-nav').click(function(){

      $("#trigg, #container").addClass('open');

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcabcwz/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that – but it's still delayed.

Comment: Updated the code with CSS3 animations instead. Does that work better?

Comment: Hmm. I tried it with a check box before, which worked in my test file but not in the CMS in which I'm implementing the website right now.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by checkbox, is "open-nav" a checkbox?

What javascript libraries is the website loading?